# Make InfoPath fileName Same as SharePoint ID

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Please can someone help as I am chasing my tail. Any help would be really appreciated.

I need to make the InfoPath file name (the same as the SharePoint Form Library ID) on close of the Infopath form.

SO I want to:

1. Go into SharePoint On-line > My Form Library
2. Click New
3. Have the InfoPath form open in to the web browser
4. Display the SharePoint Form Library ID
5. User Updates the form (or part of it) (i can do points 1-4)
6. When the user submits (or saves?) the form, the form is then stored back in SharePoint On-line with the same name as the SharePoint ID,

So if Library ID = 12 then the form Name = 12.

I am utterly lost.

Reward for the helper!

Thanks all

Tony

Answer (score 0):

you should use the submit data connection and can set the field value as the name for the file.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Submit-and-save-form-data-ae82ee07-8acb-4636-8a98-0a7bf664a998 
hope this help you.